# html2canvas on shopify error: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoadStylesheet is not defined at HTMLLinkElement.onload

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, html2canvas

I am trying to use html2canvas on a Shopify product page to convert a div to an imgURL to set as a form value. Whenever I use html2canvas, I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoadStylesheet is not defined at HTMLLinkElement.onload

When I try to pinpoint the error, it just directs me to `<!doctype html>` highlighted with the message

> Each dictionary in the list "icons" should contain a non-empty UTF8 string field "type".

This also prevents the form from posting for some reason.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#container"), {useCORS: true, logging: false}).then(canvas => {
    document.getElementById("imgURL").value = canvas.toDataURL();
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am also running it to same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if you are using ScriptTags and loading JavaScript from your own domain then you will get the error, solution is to use the cache=true when creating the ScriptTag and this will load JavaScript from Shopify's CDN and html2canvas works

Here is the code snippet in C# to create a script tag with caching:

```
dynamic scriptTagBody = new ExpandoObject();
scriptTagBody.script_tag = new ShopifyScriptTag()
{
    Event = "onload",
    Src = "https://example.com/script.js",
    DisplayScope = "all",
    Cache = true
 };
 HttpContent content = new JsonContent(scriptTagBody);
 content.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", "MyAccessToken");
 string url = "https://yourshop.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/script_tags.json";
 await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

`ShopifyScriptTag` in the above snippet is a simple POJO with those properties